# Android Chromecast Tizen Vizeo AndroidTv support.

Tags: android, chromecast, tizen, android-tv

If i want to write an app that supports all casting mediums mentioned in the title of this question, do i need to implement all the sdk's separately or do any of the sdk's have a way to wrap the functionality of the other ones?

Comment: chrome/android tv are probably ok, but everything else is competition, and they're unlikely to want to cooperate with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each SDK is specifically for that protocol / product. Vizio, Chromecast, and Android TV all support Google Cast so you can use one SDK for that.

One Cast works, you can use [this guide](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen4291/index.html) to learn how to also support Samsung Smart View.